# Is there a way to add a virtual directory to Visual Studio Development Server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, virtual-directory, webdev.webserver

I'm using the Visual Studio Development Server, with a specific port.  Is there a way to add a virtual directory to it?

EDIT:

Sorry, I wasn't very clear.  I'd like to be able to add one or more virtual directories to arbitrary physical directories.  For instance: http://localhost/c_drive/ would map to C:\, http://localhost:/d_drive/ would map to D:\, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Visual Studio Development Server is codenamed Cassini.

From [ASP.NET 2.0: A Getting Started Guide](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-getting-started/3)

```
Cassini doesn't support virtual directories, security settings, 
or any of IIS's other fancy features; it's just a very simple web server 
that gives you the basics you need to get up and running.
```

I am using the IIS which is included with Windows XP Pro. It only allows one website without tweaking but does have virtual directories. If you are on Vista, you can setup multiple sites in IIS from what I have heard.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can specify a virtual path such as `/foo` instead of `/` in the properties of your project:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I need to be able to add more than one virtual directory to an arbitrary physical directory, like you can in IIS.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Adding virtual directories is not the same as setting a virtual path for a project. Virtual directories are almost like shortcuts to folders existing elsewhere than in the web root, but is accessible to the web application as if it was in the web root folder.

Answer (score 9):

The closest you can get to virtual directories in the Visual Studio Development Server is by using OS symlinks to map a directoty outside of the Web site root to a path within the root

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can provide a physical path by launching it through command line

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0\Webdev.WebServer.exe /port:9081 /path:C:\temp\vdir
```

just do /? for a list of command line options

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't what he was asking for at all.