# How to setup a virtual directory for local host test run?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localhost, visual-studio-2017, virtual-directory

I have an ASP.net MVC 5 aplication with VS2017.
I would like to load some pictures from a network path (the pictures should not be included to the project folder structure).

I know how to add a virtual directory in IIS on my server where the application is finally running. But I dont know how to setup the same on my local computer.

On the server I can setup an Alias and a physical path.

But in my project in VS2017(properties/web) I can only press the button "create virtual directory" next to project url "http://localhost:51138/".

Can maybe someone explain how to setup an virtual directory on localhost for testing? Thank you so much.

Comment: for plain static content give a try to https://go-www.com, should work in windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Visual Studio Development Server which [does not allow virtual directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589042/2245849). You can do what you want with a local copy of IIS, creating a website that points to your development folder, and creating the virtual directory you want in that website.

1. Install a local copy of IIS. This is available to you in the
   Professional version of Windows.
2. Open IIS Manager, create a new website, and set the **Physical
   Path** to your development folder.
3. Add a binding for this website with the **Host name** set to a domain name you want to use for
   testing. I generally use ".loc" as the TLD. For example, the
   production website domain of "mywebservice.com" would be
   "**mywebservice.loc**". Use port 80 in the binding.
4. Modify your local hosts file at
   `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to include this line. Replace 
   "mywebservice.loc" with whatever domain you chose to use above 
      `mywebservice.loc 127.0.0.1`
5. In your VS project properties, set **Web-->Servers** to **Use Custom Web Server** and 
   set the **Server Url** to `mywebservice.loc` or whatever domain you chose above.

Now you can add a virtual directory just as you do in production.

I do this for all my website development primarily because nothing will happen in production that does not happen locally. You can even test using real SSL certificates this way.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. The solution sounds really good. I am using Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 Pro as well. Happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a folder in the directory of your project to mimic what will be a virtual directory and then copy some test files there.

For example, create a `documents` directory in your project directory. So the referenced path in your project will be something like `~/documents/somefile.pdf`

The server's virtual directory `documents` can then point to some some other network location.